# How can you access the base filename of a file you are sourcing in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, environment-variables

I am sourcing a file in a bash terminal that needs to export some environment varibles.

Example:

```
source linux_x86.env
```

the env file looks kinda like this:

```
export ARCH=/home/user/project/linux_x86
```

I have a bunch of different architectures to compile for and I want be able to do something like this:

```
export ARCH=/home/user/project/`basename $0 .env`
```

where `basename $0 .env` would give me the basename the env file

```
bash linux_x86.env
linux_x86
```

The above will work is a bash script but doesn't seem to work when you source the file.

Is there any way to get the same behavior from source?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-in), particularly the comment regarding the BASH_SOURCE variable.

Summary: `SCRIPT_NAME=$(basename ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})`

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up with a simplified version of the above

NAME=`basename $BASH_SOURCE .env`