# How to find out name of script called ("sourced") by another script in bash?

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In the bash script how do I know the script file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192319/in-the-bash-script-how-do-i-know-the-script-file-name)
>   [How can you access the base filename of a file you are sourcing in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178751/how-can-you-access-the-base-filename-of-a-file-you-are-sourcing-in-bash)

When using `source` to call a bash script from another, I'm unable to find out from within that script what the name of the called script is.

**file1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "from file1: $0"
source file2.sh
```

**file2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "from file2: $0"
```

**Running file1.sh**

```
$ ./file1.sh
from file1: ./file1.sh  # expected
from file2: ./file1.sh  # was expecting ./file2.sh
```

**Q: How can I retrieve `file2.sh` from `file2.sh`?**

Comment: @Matt - Especially that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/639500/45249 which suggests using `$BASH_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Change `file2.sh` to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "from file2: ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
```

Note that `BASH_SOURCE` is an array variable. See the Bash man pages for more information.

Comment: if file2 is in a different directory then `$(basename ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})` seems to work better to get the filename only. 
To get the directory only use `"$( cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")" ; pwd -P )"`

Comment: To be safe, redirect the output of `cd` to `/dev/null`. `cd` outputs the directory being changed to when `CDPATH` is set.

Answer (score -7):

if you `source` a script then you are forcing the script to run in the current process/shell. This means variables in the script from `file1.sh` you ran are not lost. Since `$0` was set to `file1.sh` it remains as is.

If you want to get the name of `file2` then you can do something like this -

#### file1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "from file1: $0"
./file2.sh
```

#### file2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "from file2: $0"
```

Comment: This invokes another shell instance and a handful of other things that are likely to be problematic and is very probably not what they were asking for,  I know it's not what I was looking for.